# Android- Parse Database edit other users' information

Tags: android, parse-platform, acl, parse-cloud-code

I'm working on a school project that is a transportation application on android.
I'm trying to edit user information from another user as logged in. When I try to edit another user's saved variable, I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is
>   not authenticated.

On my search, I saw that some people recommend changing ACL to public write on the users to edit them, I tried that and unfortunately, It didn't change anything, I still have this error. Another advice was to use cloud code or master key but I couldn't find any documentation that shows how to implement them. I'd be glad if anyone helps me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using any baas service like back4app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use masterKey in cloud code like this:

```
otherUser.save(null,{useMasterKey:true});
```

Here is a complete example using cloud code and master key:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveOtherUser", async (request) => {

  const otherUserID = request.params.otherUserID;//other user's ID;

  const user = request.user; //This is you. We are NOT gonna update this.
  //you can check your security with using this user. For example:

  if(!user.get("admin")){

    //we are checking if th requesting user has admin privaleges.
    //Otherwise everyone who call this cloud code can change other users information.

    throw "this operation requires admin privilages"

    //and our cloud code terminates here. Below codes never run
    //so other users information stays safe.
  }

  //We create other user
  const otherUser = new Parse.User({id:otherUserID});

  //Change variables
  otherUser.set("variable","New Variable, New Value");

  //Now we are going to save user
  await otherUser.save(null,{useMasterKey:true});

  //this is the response our android app will recieve
  return true;


});
```

This is our Java code for android app:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("otherUserID", otherUser.getObjectId());

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("saveOtherUser", params, new FunctionCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Boolean object, ParseException e) {
        if(e==null&&object){
            //save operation successful
        }
        else{
            //save operation failed
        }
    }
});
```

Aklına takılan olursa sor :)